# How to create api with resource not based on entity API Platform?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I need to create a GET endpoint to return a resource which is fetched from another application via http client, not based on entity. The resource I fetched is an array:

```
[
    "id" => 1234
    "first_name" => ""
    "last_name" => ""
    "email" => ""
    "country" => 1
    "country_code" => 93
    "phone_number" => "3434343"
    "nationality" => "AF"
    "professional_industry" => "Health Care"
    "job_title" => "Medical Doctor - General Practitioner"
    "specialisation" => "No specialisation"
    "career_length_month" => 1
    "career_length_year" => 1
  ]
```

Then I need to query database to fetch some data to add to the resource array.

So I created it in `src/Controller/MyController.php`:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/api/v1/get-profile", name="get_profile")
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function getMemberInfo(): JsonResponse
    {
        // step 1 : use http client to request data from another application
        // step 2 : query DB to fetch some data and add to data array
        return new JsonResponse($data, Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

But now, I would like my api return json api response format : https://jsonapi.org/.

With resource based on entity, it is supported completely by api-platform. I don't need to do much. I just adding "key" `#[ApiResource]` in entity class and config some things. Then I have a api with json api format, so easily:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "",
        "type": "",
        "attributes": {}
    }
}
```

But how about with resource not based on Entity? Is there any built-in feature of api-platform I could use, or I have to do a transformer by myself ?

Answer (score 0):

You need override the OpenAPI specification how described in documentation:
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/openapi/#overriding-the-openapi-specification

Then, in the new class, you must add the schema definition that you require, adding new PathItem instances, each PathItem require new Operation instances, etc.

Sorry for not paste examples, it require so many code. I'm working this way in a project, but it's not public for now.

I hope I put you in the way.

Answer (score 0):

The good practice is to can create a custom data provider. This custom data provider will be responsible to fetch data from the external source. Then, API-Platform will be able to use it like a regular entity.

- [Documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-providers/)
- [Full example in the API-Platform demo](https://github.com/api-platform/demo/tree/main/api/src/DataProvider)